# printing a square with sides based on loops

Tags: javascript, html

Given a number s, I am trying to print a square based on that number s. For example if s was 4 then the square would look like this

```
* * * *
*     *
*     *
* * * *
```

but the code i have does this

```
* * * * 
* *
* *
* * * *
```

When i do html += " ", it does not do what its supposed to do in the iteration. it only adds one white space. Is there a way to work around this?

```
    var html = ""
    for(var i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
      for(var j = 0; j < s; j++)
      {
        if(i != 0 && i != s-1)
        {
          if(j == 0)
          {
            html += "*";
          }
          else if(j == s-1)
          {
            html+= "*";
          }
          else 
          {
            //not working
            html += " ";
          }
        }
        else 

          html += "* ";
      }
      html += "<br>";
    }
    html += ""
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Use `whitespace: pre` to preserve whitespace.

Comment: It would be a good idea to use a monospace font too

Comment: document.getElementById("output").style.fontFamily = "monospace"

Answer (score 3):

Use `&nbsp;` instead of normal spaces. HTML collapses multiple spaces into one. nbsp stands for non-breakable space.

Comment: I did 2 minutes ago as comment to the question

Comment: No, I mean maybe give some CSS code as well, if you don't mind +1

Comment: I commented already. You don't need to name the font as your Courier suggestion, you can use the generic "monospace" font-family

Answer (score 1):

I think space `(&nbsp;)` and `*` taking width is not the same ,so you may not get the correct shape ! It is better to use fixed width with css and html element like below ..

```js
var html = "",s = 4;
    for(var i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
      for(var j = 0; j < s; j++)
      {
        if(i != 0 && i != s-1)
        {
          if(j == 0)
          {
            html += "<span>*</span>";
          }
          else if(j == s-1)
          {
            html+= "<span>*</span>";
          }
          else 
          {
            //not working
            html += "<span></span>";
          }
        }
        else {
          html += "<span>*</span>";
        }
      }
      html += "<br>";
    }
  
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
```

```css
#output {
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
span {
 width:20px;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```